# Version conflict between cvxpy and numpy: "module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd"

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, cvxpy

I'm trying to upgrade some packages and to consolidate my `requirements.txt` for an existing python program in order to move it to a docker container.

This container will be based on the tensorflow docker container, this dictates some package versions I have to use. We work under windows and we want to be able to run the program locally on our machines (at least for some time). So I need to find a configuration that works in docker and on Windows 10.

`Tensorflow 2.4.1` needs `numpy~=1.19.2`. When using `numpy 1.20`, `pip` complains that `numpy 1.20` is an incompatible version.

But when using `numpy~=1.19.2` I get the following error when importing `cvxpy`. `pip` installs all packages just fine:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cvxpy
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms import *
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\atoms\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms.geo_mean import geo_mean
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\atoms\geo_mean.py", line 20, in <module>
    from cvxpy.utilities.power_tools import (fracify, decompose, approx_error, lower_bound,
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\utilities\power_tools.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms.affine.reshape import reshape
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\atoms\affine\reshape.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms.affine.hstack import hstack
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\atoms\affine\hstack.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cvxpy.atoms.affine.affine_atom import AffAtom
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\atoms\affine\affine_atom.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cvxpy.cvxcore.python import canonInterface
  File "c:\Projekte\algo5\venv\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\cvxcore\python\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import _cvxcore
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1.)
Create a new Python 3.8 `venv` under Windows 10 and activate it

2.) Install the following `requirements.txt` via `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
cvxpy 
numpy~=1.19.2 # tensorflow 2.4.1 requires this version
```

3.) Execute the following `test.py` via `python test.py`

```
import cvxpy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

The same thing happens if I want to use `tensorflow 2.3`. In this case `numpy~=1.18` is needed, the error is exactly the same.

Searching for the error finds very few hits which sadly did not help me.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Your search should have pointed to [Hit A](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/636ec4aa4a2c1594daf5b4d04d93abef6c2003f6/doc/source/updates/index.rst) and [Hit B](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/1229). Wanting to move everything to a docker-container (which is probably linux-based) should work as the mentioned problems seem to be windows-only for now. In your question you are showing windows-based cvxpy usage (where the problem appears), but this is not the goal of moving to docker right? Acquiring cvxpy within some linux-based docker (running on windows host) will behave differently